# How to handle the default case when using 'createReducer' to create a reducer and 'on' to handle actions?

Tags: typescript, ngrx

This is how we created reducers before the `createReducer` helper method was introduced:

```
export function reducer(state: AppState, action: Action) {
 switch (action.type) {
   case "[Category List] Add Category":
         return { ...state, categories: [...state.categories, action.payload] };
   default:
     return baseReducer;
 }
}
```

The default case will handle the rest of actions that are common to all the modules.

```
export function baseReducer(state, action){
 //... COMMON CASES
}
```

With the helper the above can be written as:

```
export const reducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(addCategoryRequest, (state, { payload }) => {
     return { 
      ...state, 
      categories: payload
   };
   //WHAT ABOUT THE 'default case'
 }
}
```

How do I handle default types?

Comment: Do you need to?

Comment: I'm trying to upgrade old codes that use switches and a `base reducer` that handles the common cases. I didn't write the code I'm upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

The `createReducer` doesn't support default cases.
One option is to create a metareducer that wraps the `createReducer`.